# Jquery search objects knowing their classes

Tags: jquery

To search objects knowing their class we did like that:

```
$(".class1").each(function() {
  // code
}
```

But my problem is how to search objects knowing 2 of their classes, the following function doesn't work

```
$(".class1 class2").each(function() {
      // code
    }
```

Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :You can put multiple classes to select object by putting them one after another without space

```
$(".class1.class2").each(function() {
      // code
   }
```